# Viewport width issue on mobile on a "fixed" element

Tags: css, touch, fixed, horizontal-scrolling

I am facing an issue related to the width of a fixed element. Here is the pen:

https://codepen.io/highfield/pen/PKpXGG

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div style="position:absolute; left:20px; top:12px">
      <a href="#">left</a>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:12px">
      <a href="#">right</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sagittis, diam quis hendrerit bibendum, augue massa tempor neque, et dapibus risus ligula tempor nulla. Donec accumsan tortor eget lorem venenatis, ac tincidunt eros volutpat. Mauris
      tempus libero metus, in posuere velit scelerisque vel. Donec dapibus dolor eu tortor interdum tincidunt. Donec dignissim nisl eleifend mauris efficitur dignissim. Nullam bibendum felis a nibh maximus efficitur. Donec commodo est at maximus facilisis.
      Sed risus dui, ultricies non accumsan sit amet, volutpat sit amet dui. Sed blandit tempus feugiat. Aliquam quis felis at eros vehicula viverra in eget ante. Phasellus tempus blandit turpis, sed condimentum nisl rutrum eget. Pellentesque suscipit
      sem accumsan nunc dapibus, id volutpat eros molestie. Proin dolor nisi, sodales quis tempor sagittis, sodales non lorem. Sed porta et nisl vel scelerisque.</p>
    <p>Maecenas dapibus mattis sem. Nam suscipit urna nec massa maximus gravida. Aliquam nec arcu scelerisque, elementum orci at, dictum augue. Sed quis ex risus. Integer nec imperdiet nisi. Cras non pretium metus. In feugiat metus a ante tincidunt euismod.
      Nunc leo nisi, pellentesque non sem ut, posuere vulputate ante. Morbi elementum vel libero in egestas. Pellentesque convallis ullamcorper mi ut sagittis. Vivamus ut facilisis sapien, vel consequat ligula. Vestibulum quis vehicula dui, vitae finibus
      ante. Ut elementum suscipit nisl eu vestibulum. Integer semper aliquam metus.</p>
    <p>Proin sapien ligula, pharetra id magna sit amet, bibendum fermentum tortor. Donec ultricies ex vel iaculis mollis. Duis scelerisque tellus purus, eu eleifend arcu scelerisque ac. Curabitur varius velit nunc, sit amet sollicitudin nibh rhoncus a. Nam
      eu cursus sem, at tempor eros. Sed sodales, ante eu sagittis interdum, tortor dui feugiat diam, eu tempor mi justo sed risus. Ut non vulputate ligula, eu fermentum felis. Duis quis leo vel nulla ullamcorper viverra ut in leo. Suspendisse scelerisque,
      lorem commodo convallis consequat, ex nulla maximus nunc, ac faucibus augue risus quis arcu. Fusce porttitor, augue non malesuada consequat, odio tellus viverra diam, ut tempus mi tortor ac felis. Proin a pretium nibh, in volutpat ligula. Mauris
      non diam massa.</p>
    <p>Maecenas hendrerit tincidunt ultrices. Sed vel sem velit. Cras felis purus, commodo a velit sit amet, fringilla blandit quam. Mauris ac cursus libero. Proin volutpat ut justo ut porta. Nulla lacus arcu, hendrerit sit amet nisi sed, dictum fermentum
      erat. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
    <p>Donec nisl quam, efficitur non neque nec, vulputate rutrum lorem. Maecenas non finibus lectus. Nullam eu odio non leo mollis gravida. Aenean massa dolor, varius a hendrerit eu, molestie eu diam. Morbi lacus ipsum, ultrices et massa quis, viverra rutrum
      urna. Sed vehicula convallis massa, ac maximus diam maximus in. Aliquam non ultrices orci. Phasellus erat ante, iaculis a iaculis eget, porttitor ut nibh. Sed varius hendrerit semper. Phasellus cursus posuere semper. Curabitur pulvinar eget metus
      eget ultricies.</p>
  </div>

  <nav id="menu-left">
  </nav>

  <nav id="menu-right">
  </nav>

</body>
```

The snippet mimics a two-sided menu (not included), where a "collapsed" sidebar is 3D-translated off the window. For simplicity, the two sidebars (semitransparent green and red) are only partially translated respect their own width.

By seeing the page in "desktop mode" everything works fine. The problem becomes clear when you see the page using (almost) any mobile device. The page seems horizontally scrollable, although I don't see any reason because it does so than in the desktop view. The first "nav" element shows its width larger than the document: why? Moreover, I'm not able to find a way to constrain its width to the document itself.

In short, I would like the elements translated off the viewport should remain invisible, and no scrolling, panning, zooming or whatever else on a mobile device should reveal them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

By simply adding the "user-scalable=no" switch on the meta elements it solves the issue.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Useful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag